# Batch - Copying & Naming

Tags: batch-file

EDIT: Updated the Code with "Stephan" Edits. I tested some dummy files and everything seems to work. Thanks for taking the time out getting this fixed and working. I can now focus on moving forward on projects instead of getting outdated game development tools working. This was for the Source Engine SDK to help get game models loaded correctly with backwards compatibility.

"sodacan.dx90.dx80.vtx" should be "sodacan.dx80.vtx".

"sodacan.dx90.sw.vtx" should be "sodacan.sw.vtx".

ORIGINAL POST:
This batch file is suppose to restore missing vtx files by copying an existing vtx file. But the vtx files require a special prefix attached to them before the extension, such as "sodacan.dx80.vtx" and "sodacan.sw.vtx".

The Problem is that the script is not working as it should. The script is ran on a folder that contains VTX files with different names. The script is suppose to create copies of a single vtx file and name them. The example below shows what you start out with and the end result.

You start out with the original, such as

```
sodacan.dx90.vtx (Original File)
```

You should end with

```
sodacan.dx90.vtx (Original File)
sodacan.dx80.vtx (Copy 1)
sodacan.sw.vtx (Copy 2)
```

But I actually get this from the code.

```
awning001a.dx90.vtx (Original File)
awning001a.dx90.sw.vtx (Copy 1)
awning001a.dx90.dx80.vtx (Copy 2)
```

These files work with there associated MDL File, such as (sodacan.mdl) but the script does not touch those files at all.

Below is the code in the batch file

```
@ECHO OFF

echo Initiating VTX re-construction...

set /a count=0

for /r %%F in (.) do (
    Pushd %%F

    for %%i in ("*.vtx") do (
        for %%j in ("%%~ni") do (
            echo Fixing "%%~ni.mdl".
            if not exist "%%~nj.dx80%%~xi" copy "%%i" "%%~nj.dx80%%~xi" && set /a count+=1
            if not exist "%%~nj.sw%%~xi" copy "%%i" "%%~nj.sw%%~xi" && set /a count+=1
        )
    )

    popd
)

echo %count% reconstructed VTXes.

pause
```

Comment: You need a corresponding `POPD` at the same nested level. You also cannot use the `FOR` command to list the directory contents because any new files you renamed or copied can get pushed back into the directory to be listed again. Not understanding why you check the file extension for `.vtx` but then say you are fixing a file with the extension of `.mdl`. At no time do you process any files with a `.mdl` extension.

Comment: What's wrong? the code... Please be more specific in your problem description! we cannot know what exactly you want until you tell us...

Comment: I updated my post to explain the problem better.

Comment: I guess I am missing the .sw. part. I will add it. All I am trying to do is rebuild missing files by making a copy of an existing file and renaming the copies to what they need to be.

Comment: Looks like it fixed a ton of missing dx80 and sw files. Like wow.

"10267 reconstructed VTXes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `for %%i` loop with the following:

```
for %%i in ("*.vtx") do (
  for %%j in ("%%~ni") do (
     echo Fixing "%%~ni.mdl".
     if not exist "%%~nj.dx80%%~xi" copy "%%i" "%%~nj.dx80%%~xi" && set /a count+=1
     if not exist "%%~nj.sw%%~xi" copy "%%i" "%%~nj.sw%%~xi" && set /a count+=1
  )
)
```

and at the end use:

```
echo %count% reconstructed VTXes.
```

*Changes to your code:*

- process only the desired extension instead of processing all files and compare the extension with an `if`
- Check if the destination file exists before copying
- increment the counter only, if there was a copy
- take care of the proper filenames (two dots) with another `for %%j` (effectively removing *two* "extensions")
- adapted the last `echo` line to include the counter

(and don't forget to `popd` at the end of your `for /R` loop - there is just a limited stack for `pushd` and without `popd` you might run into that limit, generating an errormessage and exiting the script)